# Will canonical tag referencing unsecure HTTP URLs on a HTTPS page cause the unsecure message?

Tags: https, canonical-url, security-certificate, http

If a secure HTTPS page  has a canonical tag referencing the HTTP version, will this cause the message in the browser that the page is using unsecure elements and prevent the green lock icon appearing?

e.g

https://wwww.example.com/

has the following canonical tag defined:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://wwww.example.com/" />
```

I know if that if other elements on a HTTPS page are called unsecured via HTTP you get the following warning in browsers:

[image]

As opposed to the lock icon:

[image]

Will this also happen if the canonical tag is using HTTP? I've read else where that it wont, but I'd like to see a live example.

Comment: [Here's a live example.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/23156/max) (Note that HTTPS support on SE is [still experimental](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites), and in particular, some pages may still have [insecure images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221304/make-all-i-stack-imgur-com-links-protocol-relative). However, user profile pages shouldn't have any, at least if the user in question is using Gravatar for their user icon.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Web browsers do not care about canonical URLs. It is for search engine use only (specifically Google).

Additionally, canonical URLs do not affect the loading or rendering of a web page. So no assets will be loaded over HTTP which is what would cause an insecure error message.

So, no, they will not display any error message.

Comment: Do you have an example? Even though its within a canonical tag, there is still http being referenced within the page code. So makes me think it may still see the http.

Comment: Seeing and being pertinent are two different things. HTML tags have  *purpose*. This tag's purpose are of no concern to browsers (just like meta tags).

Comment: The key here is to understand what canonical links are intended for, as specified in [RFC 6596](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6596): `The canonical link relation specifies the preferred IRI from resources with duplicative content`, and only references its usage in relationship to `applications such as search engines`.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't. The unsecure warning comes about when a secured page incorporates non-secured elements. A canonical tag is a link, not an object to be incorporated into the page, so there's no reason why the padlock should care whether the URL it points to is http or https.